# I have broken my Motorola Moto E 1 Screen I was wondering if I could plug my Phone into a Monitor and a mouse

Tags: usb-on-the-go, broken-screen, external-display, mouse

I have broken my Motorola Moto E 1 Screen I was wondering if I could plug my Phone into a Monitor and a mouse, so i could use the mouse to put in my passcode.

The bad thing is that my passowrd is a pattern and the screen is unresponsive, i need to backup my stuff and i can only do that when i have unlocked the device.

So if anyone could point me in a way that would make me be able to connect my phone to a screen i would be very happy.

Comment: A mouse connected to an OTG USB adapter would likely work, but there is no way to project the screen on that device since it doesn't support MHL /Slim-port or micro-HDMI. If the screen is not at least viewable the mouse will be of no help at all. Was the device rooted prior to this, do you have ADB access at all?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome plugin called [Vysor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm) that I have used successfully in the past when my screen was completely broken and I had to extract my data. I believe it needs USB-debugging to be enabled to install on your device, but it's free so you could give it a shot. (In my case, USB-debugging was enabled before it broke because I make apps)

Once the apk is installed, it mirrors your screen on the pc and you are able to control the phone through there (and make the pattern to unlock with your mouse, or even enter the SIM-pin).

Comment: Okay yeah i have tryed that but no devices are found also do I have to unlock and download vysor on my phone